# Android RadioButtons control the color of a textview

Tags: android

i'm new to android programming and i'm making a program that changes the color of the textview item when you press one of the three radio buttons.each radiobutton corresponds to some specific color. the code compiles and doesn't give any errors , but it doesn't execute.
this is the code

```
package org.example.project2;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.graphics.Color;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    View mColorArea;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void ChangeState(View clickedbutton)
    {
        mColorArea=findViewById(R.id.color_place);
        RadioButton RB=(RadioButton)clickedbutton;
        CharSequence choice = RB.getText();
        //String Choice1=choice.toString(); this is right too
        String ChoiceString=getString(R.string.choice_string);
           String Choice1 =
                    String.format(ChoiceString, choice);
            if (Choice1=="Red")
            {
            mColorArea.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            //mColorArea.setText("red");
            }
            else if (Choice1=="Yellow")
            {
            mColorArea.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            //mColorArea.setText("yellow");
            }
            else
            {
            mColorArea.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            //mColorArea.setText("blue");
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and this is the xml part

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal" 
         >
         <RadioButton
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/red_button" 
             android:onClick="ChangeState"
             />
         <RadioButton 
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/blue_button" 
             android:onClick="ChangeState"
             />
         <RadioButton 
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/yellow_button" 
             android:onClick="ChangeState"
             />
     </LinearLayout>
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/color_place"
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to create Listeners in your onCreate. Your ChangeState method is just a normal method that isn't even called anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
Red=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton5);
        Blue=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton6);
        Green=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton7);


Red.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(isChecked)
                {
                    TextView t;
                    t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        });


Green.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(isChecked)
                {
                    TextView t;
                    t.setTextColor(Color.Green);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the below code to set the background color based on radio buttons checked

```
 color.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            if(isChecked)
            {
               RelativeLayout yourlayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
               yourlayout=.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            }
        }
    });
```